# Is there a jQuery plugin that lets me "overlay" text on top of an image, via a transparent background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, templates

Is there a JQuery plugin that lets me "overlay" text on top of an image, via a transparent background?

Similar to this:

[image]

On the bottom layer, there's a picture. Then a transparent grey. Then the white text.

How can I easily do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Use a  set opacity to around 60%, with background-color, it should look exactly like that.

Comment: But surely there's an easier way?

Comment: Easier than what suggested there is only that somebody does it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

[Like this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/gvGEd/3/) ?

It is just CSS. You can had a toggle on the `.caption` if needed... So no plugin needed.